# How to update the contents of a FigureCanvasTkAgg

Tags: python, tkinter, updating, tkinter-canvas

I'm plotting some data in a Tkinter FigureCanvasTkagg using `matplotlib`. 
I need to clear the figure where I plot data and draw new data when a button is pressed.

Here is the plotting part of the code (there's an App class defined before):

```
    self.fig = figure()
    self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
    self.ax.set_ylim( min(y), max(y) )      

    self.line, = self.ax.semilogx(x, y, '.-')   #tuple of a single element
    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=master)
    self.ax.semilogx(x, y, 'o-')
    self.canvas.show()
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
    self.frame.pack()
```

How do I update the contents of such a canvas?

Comment: Are you embedding this canvas into some GUI app, or are you just using the pyplot/pylab functionality?

Answer (score 17):

```
#call the clear method on your axes
self.ax.clear()

#plot the new data
self.ax.set_ylim(min(newy), max(newy))
self.ax.semilogx(newx, newy, 'o-')

#call the draw method on your canvas
self.canvas.draw()
```

hope this helps

Comment: For some reason, after many draw() operations, I get a max recursion depth reached error.. Which never happens without that draw call...